# 1099-DIV line 8 says "various"

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099-div

I'm using Credit Karma to file my taxes. For 1099-DIV line 8, the document says "various", but the drop down in credit karma only allow for choices of countries, not for more than one, or various countries? What do I do?

Comment: Typically, the 1099-DIV has - on the further detail pages - a repetition for each country. 'Various' is only for the summed up total.

Comment: The tax software I use happens to not ask for line 8 on 1099-DIV, and for some forms allows direct edit outside of the data entry wizard, so maybe you can get to the end or a review step and directly edit this value (or ask your provider for support for your case).

Comment: I am having the same issue. There is no country listed in any of the details just various under the totals. I wonder if CreditKarma does not support.